# On what value of $f(X)$ minimizes $E[(Y-f(X))^2|X]$

Tags: probability, derivatives, self-learning, expectation

$X$ and $Y$ are random variables.

The question is: what value of $f(X)$ minimizes $E[(Y-f(X))^2|X]$.

I am pretty sure I have found the solution to this problem by writing:
$$E[(Y-f(X)-E[X|Y] +E[X|Y] )^2|X]$$ and using the properties of the expected value.

A friend of mine instead proceeded this way:

$$E[(Y-f(X))^2|X]=E[Y^2+f(X)^2-2Yf(X)|X]=E[Y^2|X]+f(X)^2-2f(X)E[Y|X]$$

then he took the derivative of the last expression with respect to $f(X)$ and imposed the equality with 0 obtaining: $$2f(X)-2E[Y|X] = 0$$ so $f(X) = E[Y|X]$.

My question is: can I take the derivative with respect to a function of a random variable? I have only ever taken derivatives w.r.t. a variable of a function. Could I do this if I had $f(x)$( a ordinary real function)?

Comment: Do you know there is a thing called completion of squares? And by the way, you got typos all over you...

Comment: maybe you mean $f(X) = E(Y|X)$

Comment: @TroyWoo completion of squares is very nice, can't believe I did not see that way to solve the question. I am still  left with the questions on my friends method. Sorry about the typos I am trying to find and correct them.

Comment: @TroyWoo after a second look I do not think I can complete the squares. Maybe I am misunderstanding you.